# Having problems running Atom text editor on Debian Linux 9.0 and Lubuntu 17.04

Tags: lubuntu, python, debian, atom

I'm trying to install Atom to write Python scripts on Debian Linux 9.0. After following the installation procedure, which displayed no errors, when I start Atom all I see is a black window with the title Welcome - /home/Python - Atom, but nothing else happens. If I click around it takes me to their web site https://atom.io.

So I deleted and re-installed again, this time using the debian package atom-amd64.deb. After installing it (dpkg -i atom-amd64.deb) not a single error is displayed, but when I run it I get the same problem, a black screen and nothing else. I also tried to install atom in Lubuntu 17.04 zesty but I got the same problem.

Any help to get this editor running would be appreciated.

Comment: Sounds as if you are going to be filing a bug report in the near future .....

Comment: Are you running Debian and Lubuntu via virtual machine, or on a physical machine?

Comment: I advise you install atom from a ppa - https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/atom . IMO a ppa is better as you will have to manually update atom if you use the .deb.

Comment: Well, I forgot to mention that  I was running Debian and Lubuntu on a virtual machine, so I tried again installing Atom on a laptop with Lubuntu as its main OS. This time the process was flawless and Atom is working just fine. So the issue only appears when working on a VM.

Answer (score 0):

After doing more research, I found the root cause of problem:

First I have to add that the problem happened when running Lubuntu or Debian in a Virtual Machine, as when tried in a Lubuntu-based laptop all worked fine.

So I went ahead and disabled 3D acceleration in the settings of my VirtualBox VM.

After that atom worked flawless on my VM boxes. I'm not sure if this is an atom's bug or a Virtualbox one, but as long as it works I have no more questions.

Thanks for your help.